# Spring IOC GenericXmlApplicationContext does not work component scanning

Tags: java, spring

All!

I have this snippet:

```
SomeCustomClassLoader customClassLoader = new SomeCustomClassLoader();
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.setClassLoader(customClassLoader);
ctx.load(new ByteArrayResource(bytesData));
ctx.refresh();
Object testService = ctx.getBean("testService");
```

Where I'm trying to create new application context with custom classloader. Context file looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           ">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="some.base.package" />

    <bean name="testService" class="some.base.package.TestService"/>
</beans>
```

Question: why I can get the *TestService* if only it is explicitly declared in context file, if this service has *@Service* annotation it is not created. How to enable component scanning. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: See here for an example:

http://javagc.blogspot.de/2013/03/providing-gwt-rpc-service-and-other.html

Comment: Sorry did not get it. Which example?

Comment: It is the last code snippet (but they are really all just one app) :-)

Comment: And do not think that anything that I listed in my code snippets is not necessary... many things are essential. it took me quite a while to get it all going.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3815.

The solution after debugging the Spring Core could look like:

If we see into class **GenericXmlApplicationContext** we will see that is has field (xml reader)

```
private final XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(this);
```

which will be called thought the chain of invocations to ask for **BeanDefinitionRegistry**

which will be asked for getting resources during scanning for classes process where parameters will be like this one: **classpath*:some/package/name/**/*.class**

**org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#findCandidateComponents**

That means GenericXmlApplicationContext could have overridden methods responsible for this:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext() {
    @Override
    public Resource[] getResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
        if(locationPattern.endsWith(".class")) {
            List<byte[]> classes = customClassLoader.getAllClasses();
            Resource[] resources = new Resource[classes.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
                resources[i] = new ByteArrayResource(classes.get(i));
            }
            return resources;
        }

        return super.getResources(locationPattern);
    }
};
```